# How to add image on top of alert controller?

Tags: ionic-framework, alert

I want tick image with message and 1 OK button in my alert box.
Tick image should be on the top of alert box with half image outside the box and half image inside(Somewhat like this).

Is it possible to do in ionic? Please help with this

Comment: Use: `ion-popover` and create custom component. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/adding-image-to-alert-controller/178648

```
this.alert.create({
                header: HEADER,
                message: `<img src="${mapUrl}" alt="g-maps" style="border-radius: 2px">`,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: CANCEL,
                        role: 'cancel',
                    },
                    {
                        text: CONFIRM,
                        handler: ,
                    },
                ],
            });
```

Comment: But I dont want to show it in message. I already have a message saying thank you.
I want the image position like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo0VI.png
That retry option which is on the top i want to show.

Comment: how to change the size of the image here..Its very big in my alert box

Comment: the informations are in the link : "define a css class selector at the global.scss file in your project and add the class to your image."

Comment: I have image and text both in my message
I want to decrease the size of the image only

Comment: does not work for me in 2023 with Ionic v6. The class actually gets added to the element, but the definition of the global css class doesn't seem to have any effect inside the `#shadow-root`

Comment: found a workaround:
I made ALL my referenced images height smaller and put them in a subfolder of the normal actual images and refernced the subfolder. Ugly and not DRY but it works for my use case

If anyone has a better solution lmk